# Can I use a FB share dialog with a access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-share

**The situation**

I'm developing a web tool that will be used inside a iPhone/Android app.
Inside the app the User have to log into facebook, with the FB app or a regular fallback.

We discovered that the FB session between the app and the webview was not carried over. (If you logged in on FB in the app, you still had to log in to FB in the webview)

To solve this we made the App send the access token to the webview through a POST.

In the web view I use the Graph API to fetch the users FB ID.
The ID is used in a API that the App and the webview-site uses to share data.

So far so good.

**The Problem**

We want to use a share dialog on some parts of the webview.
But we don't want to login again (We want to use the Access Token for this as well)

(I cannot do any changes to the App itself so I'm stuck with what I have.
A Access Token)

**Tries**

1) I have tried to find if it is possible to use a regular Share Dialog with a Access Token. It doesn't seem to work from the documentation.

2) It doesn't work to "login" to FB with a access token from what I can tell. No way to pass the Access Token.

3) I can't create a Share Dialog with FB.ui since that function doesn't take a Access Token.

4) Using the URL Redirection method doesn't work either because you will get a login dialog. (Since I can't pass the Access Token from what I can tell)

5) I can post directly to a users feed with fb.api() and the "publish_actions" permission. With fb.api() I can pass the Access Token to the function. But the user can't control what is being sent. I'm worried that might anger users.

I could build a custom dialog for the user and send what they wrote there. That is a last resort if no other solution is found.

When I tried to test this solution in the Graph API Explorer my FB account accused my app for spamming.. So I'm not sure this is a valid solution.

**Conclusion**

It seems very difficult to share content with only a Access Token.
Solution nr 5 works but I would rather use a regular share dialog.

I know that it seems impossible according to the documentation but FB are not the best at updating their documentation. So I'm hoping someone can give me a definite answer.

**Resources**

If I understood correctly I'm only allowed to share 2 links, since I don't have enough reputation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
app_id=xxxxxxxxxx&display=popup
&href=http://google.com
&access_token=<user access token>
```

1. check your app access token first at

   graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
   input_token={token-to-inspect}
   &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}
2. check that your app has access to user public-profile

   graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
   input_token=
   &access_token=

Comment: Proper capitalization is encouraged on Stack Overflow.